# On-the-fly zonal statistics in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, zonal-statistics, rasterstats

I would like to know if there is a plugin/method in QGIS to calculate zonal statistics (mean, median, range, max, min etc.) of a raster file, corresponding to a polygon that I draw/highlight in QGIS.

For example, I have a netCDF file open displaying and I know that using the point selection tool I can find the value at that location, but if I were to highlight an area (by clicking and dragging), can I calculate the summary values of this area somehow?

I am looking for an on-the-fly solution as opposed to needing to create a shapefile and running RasterStats or similar.

Comment: You could use a scratch layer and the Zonal Stats tool.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that but wanted an on-the-fly solution as per question.